# jquery ui select menu - change value

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

How to change value for selectmenu? On click of button I need to reset to default value like this.

```
$j('#mm').val('mm');
$j('#mm').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

I looks like the value is changed, but I have the problem with the width of select menu, it becomes too small. How to update value without change widith of element?

This code cause javascript error no such method:
     $('#mm').selectmenu("value", 'mm');

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved like this one:

```
$j('#mm-button .ui-selectmenu-text').text('mm');
$j('#dd-button .ui-selectmenu-text').text('dd');
```